# Error 500 internal server error when posting long forms content

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I created a long form with multiple fields that post the typed data to a Mariadb database.
The types are all set to TEXT as the field will contain long text.

The max_allowed_packet = 1073741824 
The net_buffer_length = 1048576 
The PHP post_max_size = 500M
The memory_limit = 550M
All this seems suficiant for very long text posting to database. 
But apparently not, as it gives me a 500 error when I exceed 99100 characters :/ and works fine when I keep the posted text under that amount of characters.
What am I doing wrong ?
The error log shows : Code:500 
Message:Code:500 Message: POST /login/resident/updateresident/7 HTTP/1.1 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To find out what you're doing wrong, enable error display or look in the server error log. There you should find the actual details of the 500 error and will have far more of a clue what's going on. There's not much we can do without seeing your actual code or the real error that underlies the 500.

Comment: the error message in the log is just : Code:500 Message: POST /login/resident/updateresident/7 HTTP/1.1

Comment: Check for errors after each SQL command.  And display those errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply !
Actually none of that worked....went through all php and apache and all the conf files that controls the upload ans post max .....
A brilliant guy sent me this link :
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-20.html
It was a Mysql 5.6 bug !!!
Just updated it to 5.7 and pufff !! It worked !
GOD ! lost 3 days of my life because of this bug !